# Double press SHIFT to "Open Quickly" in Xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

In Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings I would like to register the key "SHIFT SHIFT" for the command "Open Quickly..". It makes my transition from Intellij Idea much faster and comfortable.

But the KeyBindings doesn't accept "SHIFT SHIFT" as a key... anyone know any other way?

Comment: Have you found a way to accomplish this by now?

Comment: @Johnson_145 No I haven't found any way :(

Comment: I guess you could use some 3rd party app to remap Shift+Shift to Cmd+Shift+O.

Comment: Any news on this front? :) 
//An Androider moving over to iOS

Comment: @Oskarzito The best alternative I find out as working often with Xcode was to set CMD + O for "Open Quickly".

Comment: Same as what @Oskarzito said, except I made it cmd+shift+space to mimic Spotlight since 1:10 times; instead of double shift, I find myself hitting cmd+space to try to jump to a file.